# Approximation in LinePlot from NIntegrate

Tags: plotting, numerical-integration, approximation

I am facing an approximation issue during a plot from numerical integration through NIntegrate. The code is:

```
zz[r_, r0_, \[Omega]_] = ((r0/r)^(2 \[Omega]) - 1)^(-(1/2)); 
r0 = 1;
\[Omega] = -0.5;

f111[x_, r0_, \[Omega]_] := NIntegrate[zz[r, r0, \[Omega]], {r, 0, x}]

p111 = Plot[{Re[f111[x, r0, \[Omega]]]}, {x, 0, 5}] // Quiet
```

The plot looks like this:
[image: Numerical Plot]

Although the integration can be solved analytically in Mathematica, and the code and plot looks like this:

```
In[1]:= \[Integral]((r0/r)^(2 \[Omega]) - 1)^(-(1/2)) \[DifferentialD]r
Out[2]= (r Sqrt[1 - (r0/r)^(2 \[Omega])]
  Hypergeometric2F1[1/2, -(1/(2 \[Omega])), 
  1 - 1/(2 \[Omega]), (r0/r)^(2 \[Omega])])/Sqrt[-1 + (r0/r)^(
 2 \[Omega])]

In[3]:= A[r_, r0_, \[Omega]_] := (
  r Sqrt[1 - (r0/r)^(2 \[Omega])]
    Hypergeometric2F1[1/2, -(1/(2 \[Omega])), 
    1 - 1/(2 \[Omega]), (r0/r)^(2 \[Omega])])/
  Sqrt[-1 + (r0/r)^(2 \[Omega])];
r0 = 1;
\[Omega] = -0.5;
Plot[Re[A[r, r0, \[Omega]]], {r, 0, 5}]
```

[image: Analytical solution plot]

So, there must present some errors in the numerical solution, and it must be avoided by approximation. Can anyone help with the code?

Comment: I have updated the codes.

Comment: Adding the `Method->"LocalAdaptive"` option for `NIntegrate` alleviates the numerical inaccuracies on my machine.

Comment: Can you please show me the code? @JulienKluge

Comment: That's just adding an option. Include in the list of arguments to `NIntegrate`, e.g. `NIntegrate[func, range, "Method" -> "LocalAdaptive"]`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Exclude the poles. And do not need `Quite` anymore also.  V 13.2 on windows. Basically you have an improper integral due to discontinuity at $x=1$

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
zz[r_, r0_, ω_] := 1/Sqrt[(r0/r)^(2*ω) - 1]
r0 = 1;
ω = -1/2;
f[x_, r0_, ω_] := NIntegrate[zz[r, r0, ω], {r, 0, x}, Exclusions ->{1}]
Plot[Re[f[x, r0, ω]], {x, 0, 5}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You can see the problem like this

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This seems to have caused `NIntegrate` a problem as it hit on  $x=1$ value in the domain of integration.

Answer (score 5):

Alternative: Use `NDSolve`

```
F = NDSolveValue[{int'[r] == 
Simplify[ComplexExpand[Re[zz[r, r0, \[Omega]]]], r > 0]
, int[0] == 0}, int, {r, 0, x} , Method -> "StiffnessSwitching" ]
Plot[ F [x]  , {x, 0, 5} ]
```

[image]

**or even simpler**

```
Derivative[-1][Function[r,Simplify[ComplexExpand[Re[zz[r, r0, \[Omega]]]], r > 0]]][r]
```

$\begin{cases}
 0 & r\leq 1 \\
 2 \sqrt{r-1} & \text{True}
\end{cases}$